# NSCalendar first day of week and personal settings

Tags: ios, nscalendar

In system settings in section "Mail, Contacts, Calendars" user can set any weekday as first day of week. `[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] firstWeekday]` does not return this value but returns value for current locale. Apple's Calendar app responds to changes in user's preferences.

How to get first day of week personalized by user?